# What is the correct reading order for Deadpool?

Tags: comics, suggested-order, deadpool

I have read random [Deadpool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadpool) graphic novels over the years. I would really like to start from the beginning, but I don't know where to start. Can someone post a complete reading order for me?

Comment: Let's just wait, he himself will show up and tell us

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, there's a page listing the [Chronological order](http://thecrimsonnutcase.tumblr.com/post/158004762156) of all Deadpool **appearances.** Here's the gist of it:

> **Main Deadpool Continuity**
>
> 1. Deadpool: The Circle Chase (1993) #1 - #4
> 2. Deadpool: Sins of the Past (1994) #1 - #4
> 3. Deadpool (1997) #-1 - #69
> 4. Agent X (2002) #1 - #15
> 5. Cable & Deadpool (2004) #1 - #50
> 6. Deadpool Annual (2013) #1
> 7. Deadpool (2008) #1 - #63
> 8. Uncanny X-Force (2010) #1 - #35
> 9. Deadpool vs. Thanos (2015) #1 - #4
> 10. Thunderbolts (2012) #1 - #32
> 11. Deadpool (2012) #1 - #45 & Deadpool: Dracula’s Gauntlet #1 - #13
> 12. Mrs Deadpool and the Howling Commandos (2015) #1 - #4
> 13. Deadpool & Cable: Split Second (2016) #1 - #6
> 14. Uncanny Avengers (2015) #1 - ongoing
> 15. Deadpool (2015) #1 - ongoing
>
> **Loosely fitting into Deadpool (2015) continuity**
>
> - Deadpool & the Mercs for Money (2016) #1 - #5 [Miniseries]
>     *Should be read before Deadpool (2015) World’s Greatest: Vol. 5 Civil War II*
> - Spider-Man/Deadpool (2016) #1 - ongoing
> - Deadpool & The Mercs for Money (2016) #1 - #10
>     *Should be read after Deadpool (2015) World’s Greatest: Vol. 5 Civil War II*

Everything else – and, let's face it, there was a time when Deadpool was *everywhere* – should be free of continuity and can be read whenever you want.

As a backup, [Crushing Krisis](http://crushingkrisis.com/definitive-guide-to-collecting-x-men-as-graphic-novels/definitive-deadpool-collecting-guide-reading-order/) essentially provides the same information but offers more details regarding collections and omnibuses.