# In what order should I read Deadpool TPB's?

Tags: marvel, comics, suggested-order, deadpool

With the upcoming *Deadpool* movie, I've become interested in reading his comics. For reasons of both time and money, I'm not interested in hunting down individual issues, so trade paperbacks and collections would be the way to go.

My default preference would be to read them chronologically, unless there's a compelling reason to do otherwise, but I'm having trouble even figuring out what the chronological order would be. When I search "Deadpool TPB" on Amazon, I end up with 5 entirely different TPB's that all have "Volume 1" in the title. I'm not sure how to get started.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadpool#Publication_history

Comment: Consider subscribing to Marvel Unlimited (basically Netflix for Marvel comics), which has pretty much the entire run of Deadpool comics. That would save the trouble of having to track down TPBs, and is a flat subscription fee.

Comment: The publication history is interesting to read but doesn't really tell me which TPBs are which

Comment: Related **but not a duplicate**: _[What is the correct reading order for Deadpool?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/36046/19561)_

Answer (score 1):

I would say the best place to start is at the beginning of any run. But if you want to go back to the beginning and catch all the way up, read The Deadpool Classics TPBs! They start with his first ongoing series and go all the way up to the recent series. There are 15 volumes.

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! Could you add a little more detail to this answer, e.g. with links or a list?